# Replacing gets() with fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, gets

I've been testing this struct out and I get warning about using `gets`. Somebody mentioned to use `fgets` instead and replace the end with `'\0'`. Any recommendation how I can change my code to do that?

```
void regCars(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars) {
    char again[WORDLENGTH] = "yes", model[WORDLENGTH], tmp[WORDLENGTH];
    int year, milage;

    while (strcmp(again, "yes") == 0) {
        printf("Enter model:");
        gets(model);
        printf("Enter Year:");
        gets(tmp);
        year = atoi(tmp);
        printf("Enter milage:");
        gets(tmp);
        milage = atoi(tmp);
        reg[*pNrOfCars] = createCar(model, year, milage); 
        (*pNrOfCars)++;
        printf("Continue? (yes/no)");
        gets(again);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a utility function `mygets()` that takes 2 arguments: a pointer to the destination array and its size:

```
char *mygets(char *dest, size_t size) {
    /* read a line from standard input and strip the linefeed if any */
    if (fgets(dest, size, stdin)) {
        dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0');
        return dest;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void regCars(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars) {
    char model[WORDLENGTH], tmp[WORDLENGTH];
    int year, milage;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter model:");
        if (!mygets(model, sizeof mode))
            break;
        printf("Enter year:");
        if (!mygets(tmp, sizeof tmp))
            break;
        year = atoi(tmp);
        printf("Enter milage:");
        if (!mygets(tmp, sizeof tmp))
            break;
        milage = atoi(tmp);
        reg[*pNrOfCars] = createCar(model, year, milage); 
        (*pNrOfCars)++;
        printf("Continue? (yes/no)");
        if (!mygets(tmp, sizeof(tmp))
            break;
        if (strcmp(again, "yes") != 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that you can factorize more code with a `prompt()` function that outputs the question and reads the response:

```
char *prompt(const char *message, char *dest, size_t size) {
    printf("%s ", message);
    fflush(stdout);
    /* read a line from standard input and strip the linefeed if any */
    if (fgets(dest, size, stdin)) {
        dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0');
        return dest;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void regCars(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars) {
    char model[WORDLENGTH], tmp[WORDLENGTH];
    int year, milage;

    for (;;) {
        if (!prompt("Enter model:", model, sizeof mode))
            break;
        if (!prompt("Enter year:", tmp, sizeof tmp))
            break;
        year = atoi(tmp);
        if (!prompt("Enter milage:", tmp, sizeof tmp))
            break;
        milage = atoi(tmp);
        reg[*pNrOfCars] = createCar(model, year, milage); 
        (*pNrOfCars)++;
        if (!prompt("Continue? (yes/no)", tmp, sizeof(tmp))
            break;
        if (strcmp(again, "yes") != 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Also note that this function should take the size of the `reg` array to stop prompting for more input when it is full.  As currently specified, it has the same shortcoming as `gets()`, unexpected input will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Alex: do you mind up-voting the answer you accepted?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricker than it looks. There's not much point just replacing gets with fgets(), if you then process a truncated line on over-long input and handle it as valid. You've merely replaced undefined behaviour with wrong behaviour.

```
if( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) )
{
   if(!strchr(line, '\n'))
   {
      /* line is too long, what you do is up to you, but normally
         we will discard it */
      int ch;

      while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        if(ch == '\n')
          break;

   }
   else
   {
       /* line is a normal line with a trailing '\n' (gets trims the '\n')           */
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to just discard long lines ... and long lines occur pretty frequently in text files written by computer programs.    `fgets()` can read them ... it just takes more calls, and logic to handle that.

Comment: If valid lines are unbounded, fgets() isn't your input function of choice. But of course what an over-long line means is determined by the situation, and sometimes discarding it is wrong. Silently truncating and leaving the remainder indistinguishable from a  full line is almost never correct behaviour, however.

Answer (score 0):

Just do for example

```
if (NULL != fgets(model, WORDLENGTH, stdin)) /* Read the string. */
{
  model[strcspn(model, "\r\n")] = '\0'; /* Cut off \n and/or \r, if any. */
}
```

Comment: I think this is will do it just for model, if i have multiply int's and char, is there a function that can look through all of them and replace the \n?

Comment: @Alex: `fgets()` (as well as`get()`) reads "strings" only. For reading the "year", you use `gets(tmp)`, which can be replaced as shown.

Comment: so i insert the if statement right after fgets(model)?

Comment: Yes. And you want to add some error handling for the else-case.

Comment: Also reading the documentation for the functions used I also recommend.